# php get bing rss feed titles into one var

Tags: php, rss, foreach, simplexml

I am trying with the code below to get a bing rss news feed, grab all the titles from this data to an array and then implode them all together so I have a variable with all the words together in a string so I can then create a word cloud out of this with another peice of code. So far it grabs the rss feed and print_r($doc); if you uncomment it displays the simple xml. Howver my foreach looping to grab the titles in the array doesn't seem to be working and I can't see where the error is? Thanks in advance.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://api.bing.com/rss.aspx?Source=News&Market=en-GB&Version=2.0&Query=web+design+uk");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
//print_r($doc);

$vals = array();
foreach ($doc->entry as $entry) {
$vals[] = (string) $entry->title;
}

//join content nodes together for the word cloud
$vals = implode(' ', $vals);

echo($vals);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The titles are at *rss/channel/item/title* and not where your code looks for them, at *rss/entry/title*.  Other than that, your way of getting the values is fine.

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://api.bing.com/rss.aspx?Source=News&Market=en-GB&Version=2.0&Query=web+design+uk');

$titles = array();
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $titles[] = (string) $item->title;
}

//join content nodes together for the word cloud
$words = implode(' ', $titles);

echo $words;
```

A quicky alternative, using XPath to get the titles, is:

```
$rss  = simplexml_load_file('http://api.bing.com/rss.aspx?Source=News&Market=en-GB&Version=2.0&Query=web+design+uk');
$words = implode(' ', $rss->xpath('channel/item/title'));
echo $words;
```